# Javascript Link error in Chrome which works ok in all other browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I use the following code which works perfectly in all browsers except Chrome and i'm struggling to understand why - when the button is clicked it simply does nothing:

```
echo "</div><div class='search_title'>
<!--table15--><h3>".$databack3[title]."</h3><br /><br />".$main_category."</div>
<!--end table15-->
<!--end table0-->

<div class='search_price'><h7>".$pricing."</h7><br /><br />

<form action='/productView.html' method=post name=prod_form>
<a  href='javascript:void(0);' onclick=\"document.forms['prod_form'].submit();
return false;\" class='button101' style='margin-left:80px;'>".$button_text."</a>
<input type=hidden name=PRid value=".$databack3[PRid].">
<INPUT type='hidden' name='cat_id' value=".$databack3[prodcatID].">
<INPUT type='hidden' name='for_user_id' value=".$for_user_id.">
<input type=hidden name=source value=".$source."></form></br>";
```

Comment: If this is a PHP script you should be using `$databack3['title']` instead of `$databack3[title]`. It won't solve your problem but it is wrong.

Comment: Your code works fine for me on Chrome - http://jsfiddle.net/Ft9E6/ . Probably some code you haven't included is preventing chrome from sending the form. Check Chrome console for errors (ctrl+shift+j).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it like this:

```
<div class='search_price'><h7><? echo $pricing ?></h7><br /><br />

<form action='/productView.html' method=post name=prod_form id=prod_form>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('prod_form').submit()"
class='button101' style='margin-left:80px;'><? echo $button_text ?></a>
<input type=hidden name=PRid value="<? echo $databack3[PRid] ?>">
<INPUT type='hidden' name='cat_id' value="<? echo $databack3[prodcatID] ?>">
<INPUT type='hidden' name='for_user_id' value="<? echo $for_user_id ?>">
<input type=hidden name=source value="<? echo $source ?>"></form></br>
```

the important bit being, gave the form an id and used diff onclick

```
<form action='/productView.html' method=post name=prod_form id=prod_form>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('prod_form').submit()"....
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use href='#' instead

```
<a  href='#' onclick="document.forms['prod_form'].submit();return false;" class='button101' style='margin-left:80px;'>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things unrelated to your question:

1. PHP can be used as a templating language. Why are you echoing all this HTML out as a string? Instead, try this:

   // ... assuming there is php code above this line you'd need ?>

   ```
   <div class='search_title'>
       <!--table15-->
       <h3><?php echo $databack3['title']?></h3>
       <br /><br />
       <?php echo $main_category ?>
   </div>
   <div class='search_price'>
       <h7><?php echo $pricing ?></h7>
       <br /><br />
       <form action='/productView.html' method='post' name='prod_form'>
           <a  href='javascript:void(0);' 
               onClick="document.forms['prod_form'].submit(); return false;"       
               class='button101' style='margin-left:80px;'><?php echo $button_text?></a>
           <input type=hidden name=PRid value=".$databack3[PRid].">
           <INPUT type='hidden' name='cat_id' value=".$databack3[prodcatID].">
           <INPUT type='hidden' name='for_user_id' value=".$for_user_id.">
           <input type=hidden name=source value=<?php echo $source?>>
        </form></br>
   ```
2. You should really use quotes when accessing associative arrays in PHP. ie: $myArray['key'] not $myArray[key]
3. As @BonEspresso says, use href="#" instead. Also, you should not need to return false.